# Integrating JSP web interface with Lucene index searcher

Tags: jsp, web-applications, servlets, lucene

I am building a search engine. I have written the indexer and searcher using Lucene. I have built a web interface in JSP that along with her query also record her current time and location. But being new to JSP I cannot understand how I shall integrate my JSP webUI with the Lucene index searcher. So basically I want to pass the query associated the other parameters to the Lucene index searcher and display the results back in page wise manner in browser like any other standard search engine.

In this context I have studied tutorials on Jsp and Lucene. But I could not understand how to do that. So can anyone please give any idea to do that or suggest a link from where I can learn about how to implement it.

Comment: You're building a search engine yourself? Houw about using one of the existing ones like [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr)?

Comment: I mean yes. I have seen Solr. But it looked difficult to me. Actually I already have indexed documents using Lucene and built a Web User Interface where user will submit query in Jsp. So what is left is just calling the Lucene index searcher from Jsp and showing the result back in the browser.

Comment: There are a lot of things that you need to take care of if you do it like this. Existing systems add nice features on top of lucene like caching, distributing data and make lucene easier to use, so that you don't need to be a lucene expert and can concentrate on your data. If you've found Solr difficult I don't see how you can find lucene easy ;) Maybe have a look at elasticsearch? Sorry but I really think you're doing something you shouldn't be doing unless you have exotic requirements.

Comment: Sir, can you please give a link to good tutorial on Solr from where I can learn it well?

Comment: Sure: http://www.solrtutorial.com/ for Solr, http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/ or http://www.elasticsearch.org/ for elasticsearch. Have fun!